# What is the commutator?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, commutator

$e$ and $f$ are unit vectors, $L_e$ is defined by $L_e=eL$, where $L$ is of course the angular momentum operator. A similar definition for $L_f=fL$

The commutator that I can't solve:

\begin{equation}
[L_e,L_f]=?
\end{equation}

Comment: Of the three different textbooks I have at hand (Griffiths, Sakurai & Shankar) on quantum mechanics, none of these omit explaining how to determine (a) the general commutator and (b) the angular momentum commutators. I cannot imagine other textbooks actually omitting this information...

Comment: Should this be moved to math.SE?

Answer (score 2):

As operators, you have $[L_{\vec e}, L_{\vec f}] = i L_{\vec e \wedge \vec f}$

(in units $\hbar=1$)